# User Lockout in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2013, permissions

MS SQL Server 2012 and 2008 got installed as a by-product of VS2013 installation.
Here is the screen shot of my Control Panel. 
[image]
[image]
and I have been trying to solve the following error with no luck.

[image]

I also see that a lot of questions regarding SQL Server on SO and other places on Internet are unanswered. Either by the luck a draw the problem went away or they gave up for answer.
Anyway, I have tried some solutions but in every case one step of the solution does not work for me.
If you know of a forum that I should take my question to please do not hesitate to give me your feedback.  Thanks

Comment: the error msg is very clear: you do not have the necessary permissions

Comment: Thank you.  I know that. I have tried :
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dparys/archive/2009/09/17/create-database-permission-denied-in-database-master-my-fix.aspx  
this solution to do 
SP_ADDSRVROLEMEMBER ‘darth\vader’, ‘sysadmin’

GO
and it still tells me I don't have permissions. I have no idea how to grant permission anymore, That is my problem

Comment: I found the answer in the following post. [A fantastic SO answer by AlexS which references the correct MS article to take care of admin lockout problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4188193/how-do-you-reset-the-sa-password)